# start a new layout when click on items in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a MainActivity.java and NavigationDrawer. I want to when I click on items in navdrawer, start new layout. I know I can start new Activity, but I don't want a new activity. new layout is suitable for me. is this possible???

this is my ActivityMain.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Toolbar toolbar;
protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.a1);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.khat) {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }

        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SOMETHING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return true;
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }else {super.onBackPressed();}

}
}
```

and this is my second layout that I want start when I click on items:`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#132740"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="blah blah"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is just the layout you wanna to change, there is a very simple soluction:

```
if (Case_A)
  setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

else if (Case_B)
  setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
```

But considering using Fragments:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

With fragments, you will be able to divide your code in multiples class, for each layout. It will be more readable and light:

[Here is an example](http://guides.codepath.com/android/fragment-navigation-drawer)

Comment: tnx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment in order to user multiple layout with different operation. If u just want to change the layout then u can set new layout on item click with setContentView(new layout); .